# How to find whether Tree map is loaded or not Kendo Jquery

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Jquery Tree Map with Angular. Everything is working fine, problems starts when I try to export the treemap.

I have a requirement where users can export the treeMap with viewing it.

I am rendering the Tree Map in visibility: hidden. and then trying to get the html content convert it to canvas and then to toDataURL() and using it.

But I am not able to figure out when my Tree map is completely rendered.

Data for Tree map is coming from api and I am trying to emit an event in dataBound such that I can listen it in parent component and trigger print.
But databound event gets trigger multiple times.

Any way we can handle this scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi All posting the answer such that if anyone is looking for resolution:

The dataBound is the correct event for achieving this. As for the fact that the event fires on each change, we can use "one" for attaching only one handler after the widget is initialized:

dojo for the same: https://dojo.telerik.com/IBIvuVAD/2